# Конверсия с XLM (XLMX) в XML

Tags: c#, xml, csv

Здравствуйте. Имею таблицу с множеством данных в XLMX формате:

|name|Some_info|Some_address|Telephone|Email|Site|Links|styleUrl|gx_media_links|coordinates|

и разметку под XML документ (от CSV конверсии):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

  XElement xmlf = new XElement("Folder",
      new XElement("name", "NASI PARTNERZY HANDLOWI"),
      from str in source
      let fields = str.Split(';')
      select
      new XElement("Placemark", new XElement("name", fields[0]),
          new XElement("description", fields[1]),
          new XElement("styleUrl", fields[2]),
          new XElement("ExtendedData",
              new XElement("Data", 
                  new XAttribute("name", "gx_media_links"), 
                  new XElement("value", fields[3]))),
          new XElement("Point", new XElement("coordinates", fields[4]))));
```

Возможно ли использовать данную разметку для конвертации с XLM, и как вписать информацию с разных ячеек (Some_info|Some_address|Telephone|Email|Site|Links) в один XML элемент "description" при условии, что отдельные ячейки могут быть пустыми?

```
        <Placemark>
        <name>Company name</name>
        <description>Some description</description>
        <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
        <ExtendedData>
            <Data name='gx_media_links'>
                <value>some links</value>
            </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>22.912227,52.12221,0.0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
```

Answer (score 3):

Лучшим способом будет сделать в `<description>` под элементы  `<Some_info>` `<Some_address>` `<Telephone>` `<Email>` `<Site>` `<Links>`.

Если ячейка будет пустая то этот элемент не создается.

Comment: Возможности создания подэлементов нет.